# How to implement comparison / matching in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `features` which contains features of multiple users `A,B,C` etc.

I want to match the most closely related users.

For example, if I want the most closely related match for `A` , then in the below table `A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}` and `B = {1,2,3,4}` , which means A and B are the most closely matched than `A` and `C`

How do I implement an SQL query to match the most closely related of a particular user ?

```
user     features 
------------------
A        1
A        2
A        3
A        4
A        5
A        6
B        1
B        2
B        3
B        4
C        3
C        4
```

Comment: You should define what you consider matching/similar. If A={1,2,3}, B={1,4} and C={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,...,1000}, who is the closest match to A? A and B have only 1 feature in common, while A and C have 3 in common, so "200% more". But A and C differ in basically every features of C, while A and B differ in only 1, 2 or 3 features (depending on how you look at it), but have in common that they do not support features 5 to 1000.

Comment: Yes. That is a good concern. But I think I'll keep it basic for now. Thus, as long as two users' match score is highest it should be fine (irrelevant of other unmatched features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just count the number of features in common with a self-join:

```
select f.user, f2.user, count(*) as num_in_common
from features f join
     features f2
     on f.feature = f2.feature and f.user <> f2.user
where f.user = @user  -- whatever user you want to compare to
group by f.user, f2.user
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: `f.user < f2.user` I guess you mean `<>`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Why? There's no point bringing back each combination twice but reversed. If you have the count for users `a,b` no need to also calculate it for `b,a`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I didn't see that this query is for all combinations. But OP asked for "most closely related of a **particular user**". So there also should be `where f.user = 'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e73813/13

```
Select 
  user, count(features in (Select features from t where user = 'A')) Count
From 
  t
Group By user
Order by Count Desc
```